# NP-Hard problems instances

Tags: complexity-theory

I'm trying out different optimization heuristics. Do you know of any place where I can access instances and solutions to NP-Hard problems, other than TSPLIB?

Comment: SAT ([Sat Competition](http://www.satcompetition.org/)), CP (minizinc, xcsp, ...) and mathematical-optimization communities ([Mittelmann](http://plato.asu.edu/bench.html), [MIPLIB](http://miplib.zib.de/)) have tons of instances. But as with TSPLIB, you will compete against decade-long research (and commercial software, especially in regards to math-opt). Besides that, every good research paper, given some problem like bin-packing, vehicle-routing and so on, will do evaluation against open instances (e.g. Taillard @ Job-Shop-Scheduling; where some instances might be unsolved for decades).

Comment: It is not for research. It's a for a small demonstration and I didn't want to use the TSP or Knapsack problems, as they are the most frequent ones. Thanks for your suggestions.